# How do I call a native library from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, com, native

What is the best solution to access c# code via native code (C++)?

I have C# code which I want to call from native project, so I'm considering writing a COM wrapper but I wonder whether there is a better option (framework/design pattern/architecture etc.) available in .NET?

Comment: Using COM Interop is your best bet.

Comment: Who is close-voting this I wonder? The question is which approach is the industry practice. It looks like there's too much unused close votes out there.

Answer (score 1):

COM interop is without a doubt the best bet. It's a known, supported framework for achieving exactly what you want to achieve.

There is another alternative however - it is possible to edit the IL code inside a compiled .NET assembly to flag methods within the assembly as native exports. A detailed breakdown of the changes can be found in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16310/How-to-Automate-Exporting-NET-Function-to-Unmanage).

Robert Giesecke has created [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to simplify this process using simple method attributes. A NuGet package can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports).